# How to loop through data and wait after certain number of executions

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to understand the algorithmic logic of executing some code a set number of times, but breaking the executions into a set number, then pausing for a time before executing the next set of times.

Should I be incorporating a Promise structure (async/await) into the code to improve my understanding?

In this code, at 500 executions, the algorithm should pause some set amount of time and then resume the next 500 executions.

It looks as though all the code executes, then the timeout is executed.

I'm confused though, the `setTimeout()` doesn't even wait 5 seconds.

Constructive criticism appreciated.

**OUTPUT:**

```
> node test.js

Execute code 1
Execute code 2
Execute code 3
.
.
.
Execute code 2398
Execute code 2399
        Execution 2400
Execute code 2401
Execute code 2402
.
.
.
Execute code 2598
Execute code 2599
        Execution 2600
Execute code 2601
Execute code 2602
.
.
.
Execute code 2654
Execute code 2655
i = 500 Resume at Thu Jul 15 2021 19:53:56 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) 
i = 1000 Resume at Thu Jul 15 2021 19:53:56 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) 
i = 1500 Resume at Thu Jul 15 2021 19:53:56 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) 
i = 2000 Resume at Thu Jul 15 2021 19:53:56 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) 
i = 2500 Resume at Thu Jul 15 2021 19:53:56 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

**ALGORITHM:**

```js
let reference = 2655
for (let i = 1; i <= reference; i++) {
  if (i % 500 === 0) {
    console.log(`counter = ${i}`)
    console.log(`Execute code ${i}`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      let time = new Date()
      console.log(`i = ${i} Resume at ${time} `)
    }, 50000)
  } else if (i % 100 === 0) {
    console.log(`\tExecution ${i}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`Execute code ${i}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I incorporate a Promise structure (async/await) into the code to improve my understanding? Yes I Agree with (async/await)

Comment: How would I incorporate it?

Comment: It seems to be working correctly, `i = ${i} Resume at ${time} ` lines are printing after 50seconds.

Comment: Your misunderstanding could be that `setTimeout()` does _not_ interrupt the current flow of operations but instead triggers a function to be executed at a future point in time. In your case 50 seconds after executing  the statements in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with an `async` function, `promise` and `await`. But the following will also work, using a simple `setInterval()`:

```js
const max=2655,m=500,t=5000;
var n=0;
const intv=setInterval(doit,t);
doit(); // do the first chunk immediately!

function doit(){
 for (let i=m;i--;){
  n++; // do whatever needs doing here ...
  if (n>=max) {
   clearInterval(intv);
   break;
  }
 }
 console.log(n,new Date());
}
```

The problem with your code was that you executed a number of `setTimeout()`calls within a loop at more or less the same time. The functions inside these calls were then executed in quick succession about 50 seconds after the main loop had already finished.

```js
const data=[...new Array(2655)].map((_,i)=>i),m=500,t=5000;
var n=0, SUM=0;

const intv=setInterval(doit,t);
doit(); // do the first chunk immediately!

function doit(){
 data.slice(n,n=n+m).forEach(sum);
 // do whatever needs doing here ...
 if (n>=data.length) clearInterval(intv);
 console.log(Math.min(n,data.length),SUM,new Date());
}

function sum(v){SUM+=v}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see that there are a lot of pieces to this puzzle that I did not have. And your solution makes clear that my ultimate problem is a bit more complex.

Comment: The actual problem is a data.forEach(). What I see from your example is that at a certain point in the processing if the interval is at N, I need to reset the interval and the run the function on the element.

Comment: Tipp: you can operate on chunks of your data by doing something like `data.slice(n,n+500).forEach(...)`.

Comment: Woah! That's brilliant!

Comment: I see, the tip is how to incorporate my problem into your example.

Comment: I added a second snippet with a `data` array.

Comment: Amazing amount of skill here. What purpose does '_' serve in the map()?

Comment: The `_` is simply a function argument ( the current value of the array element) that I don't use. It could be any valid variable name instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234949/discussion-between-ken-ingram-and-carsten-massmann).

Answer (score 1):

### How to make asynchronous code wait before continuing

When you use the `async` operator before a `function`, you turn it into an `async` function.

Inside an async function, you can use the `await` operator before asynchronous code to tell the function to wait for that operation to complete before moving on.

In this example, we’ve turned `asyncFn()` into an async function. We’ve also prefaced the `window.fetch()` call with the `await` operator.

```js
async function asyncFn () {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('Async Fetch', data);
    });
    console.log('Async Message');
}
asyncFn();
```

When this runs, `Async Fetch` and the returned `data` are logged into the console before `Async Message.` The function waited for the `window.fetch()` Promise to settle before continuing.

Comment: Where is the pause in this code after a chunk of 500 calls was made?

Comment: I understand how async works conceptually.

Comment: I have to study on code more to pause at 500 calls!

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function test(reference = 2655) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= reference; i++) {
    if (i % 500 === 0) {
      console.log(`counter = ${i}`);
      console.log(`Execute code ${i}`);

      // Wait five seconds
      await new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let time = new Date();
          console.log(`i = ${i} Resume at ${time} `);
          res();
        }, 5000);
      });

    } else if (i % 100 === 0) {
      console.log(`\tExecution ${i}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Execute code ${i}`);
    }
  }
}

test();
```